# How to determine unknown array to array function using TensorFlow?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras

For some unknown function that looks like this:

```
def unknown_function(input_array): # where input array could be, for example, a 3 by 3 numpy array
    # does some unknown operation on input array 
    # to determine output array of same shape
    return output_array
```

How would one create a TensorFlow model to find the output array for any arbitrary input array, given a sufficiently large data set of input output array pairs with which to train the model?

Comment: This is probably a theoretical/statistics question first and foremost, no? In any case, this is probably too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AMC I don't think so. I've seen examples in the documentation going from an input array to a scalar: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression. I am just a little confused on how to implement a similar type thing when the output is an array instead.

Comment: Are you more concerned about the theoretical or the practical difficulties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to approximate a function by simpler functions. It depends a lot on the kind of function you're trying to approximate what's the best way to go about it. Is it continuous? How complex is it? Etc.

Try to find out what the behaviour of your function is. If it's continuous, and the input lies within a compact subset of R^n, then the [universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) says that it can be approximated through neural networks.

This does not however mean that that's the best way to go. Maybe [least-squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares) fitting of Fourier coefficients, or of monomial factors might already be enough to approximate your function well (this is usually a lot cheaper).

Look at different methods of approximating functions, and look at the properties of your function, and see what method seems most appropriate. Try to go for cheaper options (like least squares) first, and if those don't work, look at more expensive options (like deep neural networks).

Test your methods by not training on all available data and testing on the unused data. Also look at what type of output you get in order to determine what a good loss function is.